# Interpreting fisher’s Z transformation and correlations

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, interpretation, fisher-transform

Part of my planned analysis in a paper is testing the difference in strength of correlations between depression and other things like social relationships and quality of life. This test is set up with two independent groups.

My question: if neither group shows a significant correlation with depression and another variable does it still make sense to test their difference? What I am most interested in is this difference. Please let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: Are the variables (depression, social relationships, quality of life) measured on a continuous scale?

Comment: @dipetkov yes, they are continuous!

Comment: Have you considered modeling all data and variables in one regression with depression as the outcome and a *group* indicator? Since you are interested in differences between the two groups, let the group indicator interact with all other predictors. In R formula syntax: depression = group * (1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + ...). Then your hypotheses are equivalent to non-zero interaction terms?

Comment: I've thought about this and when I run it I do get mostly consistent results. There are two main predictors I'd use. One is the absolute magnitude of a deviation score and the other is an unbound deviation (both already created), which is standard for this area of research, so I don't want to mess with that. The absolute magnitude is not normally distributed (this only makes the residuals weird in one regression), but the unbound version is. Both have homogeneity of variance, so that's okay.

Comment: The distributional assumptions (normally distributed with constant variance) are about the errors, not the predictors. That's why we assess goodness of fit with qqplots of the residuals and plotting residuals against predicted values (of depression, in your case).

Comment: Right, I always forget that and confuse them, thank you. My residuals for one model look trimodal within a normal curve, but sharp. I guess I'll keep messing around. Thank you for the help!